# What is the difference between finish() and ActivityName.this.finish()?

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-finish

Is there any difference between `finish()` and `ActivityName.this.finish()`? If we have activity with name `SampleActivity`, we can finish it by calling `finish()` and by `SampleActivity.this.finish()`. What is the difference?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most of the time it's the same except if you are inside an inner class.

In that case the second notation is used to disambiguate calls to the containing activity's methods.

For instance:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    finish(); // the activity's finish()

    new Runnable() {

        private void finish() {
            ...
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            SampleActivity.this.finish(); // the activity's finish()
            finish(); // the runnable's finish()
        }
    };

    new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            SampleActivity.this.finish(); // the activity's finish()
            finish(); // the activity's finish() (because the inner class doesn't hide it
        }
    };
}
```