# What can be the possible use case for finishActivity()

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-fragments

As i already know about `Finish() and FinishActivity()`.  i.e

`finish()` Call this when your activity is done and should be closed.

`finishActivity()` is used to finish another activity that you had previously started with `startActivityForResult(Intent, int);`

i want Briefly about this with sample Example code. For Understanding how it works.

Comment: i want Briefly about this with sample Example code. For Understanding how it works.

Answer (score 15):

`finish()` Call this when your activity is done and should be closed. The ActivityResult is propagated back to whoever launched you via onActivityResult().

`finishActivity(int requestCode)` is used to finish another activity that you had previously started with startActivityForResult(Intent, int);

**Edit**

Like if you simply write `finish();` then it just gonna finish your current activity in which you are, but when you use `finishActivity(1001)` then `1001` is request code which you have passed from `startActivityForResult(intent, 1001);` so it will finish your that activity which you came from

Example.

```
@Override 
        public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) { 
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) { 
                        finish(); 
                        finishActivity(107); 
                        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Menu.class); 
                        startActivity(inten); 
                        return true; 
                } 
                return false; 
        }
```

So above example will finish your current activity as you have written `finish();` and also finish your previous activity as we have written `finishActivity(107);`, where i already told you that `107` is code that you pass from your other activity.

Let's suppose you have 2 activity (Activity A and Activity B), Main Activity A is the Starting Activity. Activity B will run on top of Activity B and is a Blur View. and when i you are redirecting to the Activity B you are not finishing activity A.  and you are starting Activity B like this

```
startActivityForResult(intent, 107);
```

so in activity B you have

```
@Override 
            public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) { 
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
                    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) { 
                            finish(); 
                            finishActivity(107); 
                            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Menu.class); 
                            startActivity(inten); 
                            return true; 
                    } 
                    return false; 
            }
```

which will finish your both activity A and B.

Hope this is simple and clear.

Comment: i know that but ,i want sample Example on it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117690/whats-the-difference-between-finish-and-finishactivityint-requestcode-in-and  and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13394136/what-is-the-difference-between-finish-and-activityname-this-finish

Comment: @RKK, updated answer, please have a look.

Comment: where we are calling FinishActivity()

Comment: Wherever you want in your code. in simple words `When you want to finish other activity from current activity that time you have to use finishActivity()`

Comment: suppose there three Activity , one to two to three from third Activity i want to close first Activity ..i am using FinishActivity(); but it is not working

Comment: @RKK, Whether my answer worked or not.

Comment: @RKiranKumar it will not work because third is not the starting activity for first.